# Using Mustache.js in Render HTML in Email Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-email, mustache, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have some objects with unpredictable properties and I want to use Mustache.js to render HTML content in email to send it to my user's emails. And this is my code:

In my HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Person person = new Person
                               {
                                   Name = "Dona",
                                   Email = "dona3315@gmail.com",
                               };
    PartialViewResult path = PartialView("PartialViewEmail");
    string tmp = path.ViewName;
    string resultRenderHtmlEmail = RenderRazorViewToString(tmp, person);

    return View();
}

public ActionResult PartialViewEmail(Person model )
{
    return PartialView(model);
}

public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

This is my PartialViewEmal.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person

<script src="~/Scripts/mustache.js"></script>
<h1>This is razor partial view that demo for body of email</h1>
I'm @Model.Name and I'm @Model.Email years old.
<div id="sampleArea">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var data = {
            employees: [
            {
                firstName: "Christophe",
                lastName: "Coenraets"
            },
            {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Smith"
            }
            ]
        };
        var template = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}" +
                                    "<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>" +
                                    "{{/employees}}</ul>";
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#sampleArea').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

And this is result of resultRenderHtmlEmail :

```
<script src="/Scripts/mustache.js"></script>
<h1>This is razor partial view that demo for body of email</h1>
I'm Dona and I'm dona3315@gmail.com years old.
<div id="sampleArea">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var data = {
            employees: [
            {
                firstName: "Christophe",
                lastName: "Coenraets"
            },
            {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Smith"
            }
            ]
        };
        var template = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}" +
                                    "<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>" +
                                    "{{/employees}}</ul>";
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#sampleArea').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't understand mustache.js !

What should I do ?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

As you know a javascript code executes at client side. But mail clients and mail services will not support executable code in email messages.

Also Razor view engine don't support executing js. So you can't template you email messages with any js templators.

Comment: How about Nustache.NET in Server @YD1m ?